# Floated image overflows accordion div

Tags: jquery, css-float, accordion

I have an accordion that I have been developing and have an issue with a floated image. Everytime the image is taller than the text in the same div, the image overflows outside of the div on top of the next accordion h3 tag.  I have a live example of this at http://vozpc.com/accordion.html I put all the code in that file so you can see. I will add it here as well.

CSS

```
#accordion div {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  width: 95%;
  display: inline-block;
}

#accordion h3 {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 8px 11px;
  font-family: Oswald, sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-weight: 700;
  width: 95%;
  margin: 5px;
}

#accordion div p {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.icon-expand,.icon-collapse {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.blue h3 {
  background: #377ad0;
  color: #fff;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="blue" id="accordion">
  <h3>Enter Title 1</h3>
  <div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x200" style="margin-right: 10px; float: left;">
    <p>Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet jerky capicola shank ball tip venison.
    Prosciutto kielbasa chicken, pork loin shoulder fatback frankfurter
    tenderloin short loin andouille capicola filet mignon. Turducken boudin
    prosciutto pork, ball tip tri-tip pork belly pork loin. Frankfurter
    kielbasa ball tip short ribs pork belly, ham hock chicken meatball
    brisket beef flank jerky. Cow hamburger meatloaf doner short ribs
    turducken ham tenderloin ground round flank jerky jowl corned beef
    spare ribs. T-bone salami kielbasa boudin biltong short loin hamburger
    beef pancetta sirloin tenderloin shank ball tip.</p>
</div>

<h3>Enter Title 2</h3>

<div>
    <p>Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet jerky capicola shank ball tip venison.
    Prosciutto kielbasa chicken, pork loin shoulder fatback frankfurter
    tenderloin short loin andouille capicola filet mignon. Turducken boudin
    prosciutto pork, ball tip tri-tip pork belly pork loin. Frankfurter
    kielbasa ball tip short ribs pork belly, ham hock chicken meatball
    brisket beef flank jerky. Cow hamburger meatloaf doner short ribs
    turducken ham tenderloin ground round flank jerky jowl corned beef
    spare ribs. T-bone salami kielbasa boudin biltong short loin hamburger
    beef pancetta sirloin tenderloin shank ball tip.</p>

    <ul>
        <li>List Item 1</li>

        <li>List Item 2</li>

        <li>List Item 3</li>

        <li>List Item 4</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<h3>Enter Title 3</h3>

<div>
    <p>Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet jerky capicola shank ball tip venison.
    Prosciutto kielbasa chicken, pork loin shoulder fatback frankfurter
    tenderloin short loin andouille capicola filet mignon. Turducken boudin
    prosciutto pork, ball tip tri-tip pork belly pork loin. Frankfurter
    kielbasa ball tip short ribs pork belly, ham hock chicken meatball
    brisket beef flank jerky. Cow hamburger meatloaf doner short ribs
    turducken ham tenderloin ground round flank jerky jowl corned beef
    spare ribs. T-bone salami kielbasa boudin biltong short loin hamburger
    beef pancetta sirloin tenderloin shank ball tip.</p>
</div>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$(function() {
  $("#accordion").accordion({
    heightStyle: "content",
    collapsible: true,
    active: false,
    autoHeight: true
  });          
  $("#accordion").accordion();
  $("#accordion").accordion("option", "icons", {
    'header': 'icon-expand',
    'activeHeader': 'icon-collapse'
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because the accordion is assigning "display:block" to your accordian div in firefox.  Interestingly it assigns "display:inline-block" in Chrome and later IE.

You can either add an element that clears the image float after your paragraph block:

```
<div class="blue" id="accordion">
   <h3>Enter Title 1</h3>
   <div>
      <img src...>
      <p>Some description...</p>
      <div style="clear:both;" />
   </div>
   ...
```

Or try adding "overflow:auto" to parent element--per "The Overflow Method" from http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/ :

```
#accordion div {
    overflow:auto;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    width: 95%;
}
```

Comment: I did try this but for some reason it breaks the accordion not allowing it to collapse. I left it with !important on the live example to see what I am talking about. http://vozpc.com/accordion.html